# Optimized solution to retrieve data from DB instead of recursive function

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, vb.net

I've written recursive function to retrieve this parent/child style menu from database:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <a href='#'>level1-a</a>
    <ul> 
      <li>
      <a href='#'>level2-a1</a>
    <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>level3-a11</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>level2-a2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>level1-b</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>level1-c</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know it's not a good idea to write such function for retrieving data from database with a recursive function, sometimes it takes long time to run.

It's my algorithm (**C#** and **VB.net** code is provided):

```
my_function (ID){
 WHILE (read_from_table){
   PRINT data
     my_function(child_id)
 }
}
```

**C#** code: http://pastebin.com/hsqhYF72 
**VB.net** code: http://pastebin.com/HnyrYnab

Is there any type of variable that is able to store such structure of data to search inside it instead of connecting to a database continually?

Comment: How big is the table?  You could read table into a Dictionary<string, List<string>> with the key the MenuParent once.

Comment: @Blam It's small, less than 50 rows.

Comment: Why don't you use a recursive **SQL** to retrieve this information in a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you want to retrieve all the relevant records at once into an in-memory collection, and then read from that memory collection during your recursion.  The paradigm of memoization/caching of records will make this simple, as well as separating your data-access logic from business logic.

First, create a `static` method for retrieving data that grabs data from the database the first time, but makes use of its in-memory collection on subsequent calls.  I'm assuming that since you are passing `fTableName`, this method may or may not be used with multiple tables, so the cache is capable of storing multiple tables at once (using a `Dictionary` keyed on the table name), and treats requests to different tables separately. (WARNING: untested code, but should give you the idea):

```
private static Dictionary<string, DataTable> _menuCache = null;
public static DataRow[] GetMenuLayer(string fTableName, string fID, string fClause)
{
    if (_menuCache == null) _menuCache = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();
    if (!_menuCache.ContainsKey(fTableName)) { 
        // retrieve all records from the database the first time
        SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM " + fTableName;
        ...
        _menuCache[fTableName] = result;
    }

    // query appropriate records from the cache
    var dt = _menuCache[fTableName];
    return dt.Select("MenuParent = " + fID + " AND Visible=1 AND " + fClause);
}
```

Since this method is `static`, its data is saved during the entire request/response cycle, but *not* between responses.  So this will reduce generating the menu to a single database call, while each time the page is loaded, the data is still loaded new.  If your menu data is relatively static, you could go to the next level using the .NET cache with a timeout that will store the database results, for say 30 minutes at a time before refreshing.  Then the page could be loaded many times with only a single database call.

The code in your `GenerateNestedMenus` that retrieves data from the database would instead make a call to `GetMenuLayer` with the appropriate parameters.  This method then is responsible for retrieving the data in whatever method it can (the former method doesn't need to care how it gets there).  Behind the scenes, the first time a table `fTableName` is requested, the *entire* table is downloaded into a local memory cache.  Then that memory cache is queried in subsequent calls according to the parameters to return the result rows that can be iterated (this assumes that your dynamic filter logic `fClause` is not too complicated, because `dt.Select(` only understands a very small subset of basic `T-SQL` logic):

```
public string GenerateNestedMenus(string fTableName, string fID, string fClause)
{

    DataRow[] dt = GetMenuLayer(fTableName, fID, fClause);

    int i = 0;
    string temp = null;
    for (i = 0; i <= dt.Length - 1; i++) {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ChildCounter(fTableName, dt[i]["id"])) > 0) {
            temp = "<li>" + Constants.vbCrLf + "<a href='#'>" + Strings.Trim(dt[i]["MenuName"]) + "</a>" + Constants.vbCrLf + Constants.vbTab + "<ul> ";
            _temp += temp;
            GenerateNestedMenus2("menus", dt[i]["id"], fClause);
            _temp += Constants.vbTab + "</ul>" + Constants.vbCrLf + Constants.vbTab + "</li>" + Constants.vbCrLf;
        } else {
            //For rows they have not child
            temp = Constants.vbTab + "<li><a href='#'>" + Strings.Trim(dt[i]["MenuName"]) + "</a>" + "</li>" + Constants.vbCrLf;
            _temp += temp;
            GenerateNestedMenus2("menus", dt[i]["id"], fClause);

        }
    }
    return _temp;
}
```

This is a rough idea of the approach to a solution, which may require some tweaking and experimenting to get everything working.

Comment: would you please explain `var dr in dt.Rows`? what is `var`?

Comment: `var` is [**implicit variable declaration**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).  If the type is known at compile-time, you can use `var` instead of explicitly declaring the type.  The type is actually `DataRow`, so it's the same as saying `foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {`.

Comment: How can I access table columns? `dr("ID")` returns `'Rows' is not a member of 'System.Array'.`

Comment: You posted both `C#` and `VB` code, so I picked `C#` since I'm more familiar with that.  It appears you are most familiar with `VB.Net`?  If so, why didn't you just stick with the language you are comfortable with?  I could have posted my answer in VB instead.  You can also try converting it automatically with a tool like this one: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Can you add a comment with a code sample that you are currently trying?  There is no `Rows` in `dr("ID")`, so it seems odd that should return an error like that.  Perhaps the error is on a different line of code than the part you commented?

Comment: `Dim var As DataRow
For Each var In dt.Rows
   x &= var("ID")
Next`

Comment: You want `For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows`.  Then use `dr`, i.e., `x &= dr("ID")`.  There is no conversion of `var` from C# to VB.Net, so the converter may be confused as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23718/discussion-between-maysam-and-mellamokb)

Answer (score 1):

You could get the data into a dataset and then use the select method on the datatables in the recursive function like this:

```
private sub getUL_String()
    Dim datasetRecs As New DataSet
    Dim datarowParents As DataRow
    Dim finalStringUL As String = ""
    //FILL your dataset here.
    //Table 0 will be your top level parents.
    //Table 1 will be all records.
    For Each datarowParents In datasetRecs.Tables(0).Rows
        //do processing to datarowFiltered row.
        finalStringUL = "fill in your UL stuff for this record"
        finalStringUL &= getChildren(datasetRecs.Tables(1), datarowParents("id"),    fClause)
    Next

    finalStringUL
End Sub


Private Function getChildren(ByRef datatableROWS As DataTable, ByVal currentID As String, ByVal fClause As String) As String
    Dim currentRow As DataRow
    getChildren = ""
    For Each currentRow In datatableROWS.Select("MenuParent=" & currentID & " and " & fClause)
        //do processing to datarowFiltered row.
        getChildren = "fill in your UL stuff for this record"
        getChildren &= getChildren(datatableROWS, currentRow("id"), fClause)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes a pure Dictionary approach.
All you are processsing is Int (id).
I find DataTables to be slower and bulkier.
And it takes an approach of getting all MenuParent.

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>> dDB = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();
public List<int> ReadData(string fTableName, string fID, string fCluase)
{
    string key = fTableName + "_" + fCluase;  
    if (dDB.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> sDB = dDB[key];
        if (sDB.ContainsKey(fID)) return sDB[fID];
        return new List<int>();
    }

    string SQLCommand = "SELECT id, MenuParent FROM " + fTableName + " where Visible=1 AND " + fCluase + " order by MenuParent";

    SqlDataReader DR = new SqlDataReader();
    Dictionary<string, List<int>> nsDB = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    int _id;
    string _fid;
    string _fidLast = string.Empty;
    List<int> _ids = new List<int>();
    while (DR.Read())
    {
        _id = DR.GetInt32(0);
        _fid = DR.GetString(1);
        if (_fid != _fidLast && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fidLast))
        {
            nsDB.Add(_fidLast, _ids);
            _ids.Clear();
        }
        _fidLast = _fid;
        _ids.Add(_id);
    }
    nsDB.Add(_fid, _ids);
    dDB.Add(key, nsDB);
    if (nsDB.ContainsKey(fID)) return nsDB[fID];
    return new List<int>();
}
```